# Nested getElement functions doesnt work on casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Hello I am learning casperjs. But I am having a problem with the code

```
document.getElementsByClassName('darkest dps64 profiles-show fls45 links _a _jm')[0].getElementsByTagName('a').length;
```

It simply doesnt work when I run the script. But when I write in the Mozilla/chrome console it works. In console it gives me "5" as I expected but on cmd it gives me

```
TypeError:'undefined is not an object <evaluating 'document.getElementsByClassName('darkest dps64 profiles-show fls45 links _a _jm')[0].getElementsByTagName('a').length;
```

I know that undefined means it cant find it on the page but when I take a screenshot it show that it is on the right page. So it must find? But unfortunately it doesn't. my code is down below. Thanks for your help:)

```
phantom.casperPath = 'C:/casperjs';
phantom.injectJs(phantom.casperPath + '/bin/bootstrap.js');
var casper = require('casper').create({
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages: false,//The script is much faster when this field is set to false
        loadPlugins: false,
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'
    }
});

casper.start().thenOpen("https://angel.co/mike_greenfield?utm_source=people", function () {
    console.log("site opened");
});

casper.then(function () {
    this.capture('pic.png');
});
casper.then(function () {
var howmanylinks= document.getElementsByClassName('darkest dps64 profiles-show fls45 links _a _jm')[0].getElementsByTagName('a').length;
    console.log(howmanylinks);
});
casper.then(function () {
    casper.exit();
});
casper.run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM can only be accessed inside of `casper.evaluate()`. Although, `document` is available outside, it doesn't do anything:

```
casper.then(function () {
    var howmanylinks = this.evaluate(function(){
        return document.getElementsByClassName('darkest dps64 profiles-show fls45 links _a _jm')[0].getElementsByTagName('a').length;
    });
    console.log(howmanylinks);
});
```